# Deserializing JSON with Json.NET fails if internal string array exists

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am using Json.NET 6.x and I noticed weird behaviour:

If I want to deserialize this simple JSON, I get an error:

The code to deserialize:

```
 object o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

and the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Username": "tb386",
    "TimestampUpdated": "2015-01-19T18:49:52.771571+01:00",
    "AuthTokens": [
        "Ua7JR5E7hSAxjafp6dpMrvw3HlICW3ZZdDuArMaU5ks="
      ]
  }
]
```

The error I get is:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: U. Path '', line 0, position 0.

If I remove the array, it works fine. But all I have to do, is to remove the string inside the array, making it empty:

```
[
  {
    "Username": "tb386",
    "TimestampUpdated": "2015-01-19T18:49:52.771571+01:00",
    "AuthTokens": [ ]
  }
]
```

and then it works fine. I should also note that the serialized JSON was produced by the Newtonsoft library, so the source is the same library!

If I try a validator (like http://jsonlint.com/) on the JSON with the array, it valides OK!

Can anyone help me out here?

> Additional information: Even if I add a string inside VS and write the JSON hardcoded, it fails!

```html
string text =  "[ {\"Username\": \"tb386\",\"TimestampUpdated\": \"2015-01-19T18:49:52.771571+01:00\",\"AuthTokens\": [\"Ua7JR5E7hSAxjafp6dpMrvw3HlICW3ZZdDuArMaU5ks=\"] } ]";
  
object o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

Version info on Newtonsoft dll:

[image]

Comment: Show some relevant stuff instead: what does the model to which you're deserializing look like?

Comment: That is completely irrelevant. I am deserializing to "object", so forget the model. This is as basic as it gets.

Comment: Seems to work fine [in linqpad](http://imgur.com/6JhkcaF)?

Comment: yes, it all works in all validators I have tried =) I also mentioned that above. The strange thing is that Newtonsoft does not allow it, giving me the error as mentioned above.

Comment: What's the exact version number for Json.NET that produces the error?

Comment: Check the image - it's deserialised properly using newtonsoft in linqpad

Comment: I did look at it, strange. And I had an image before with all the version info, but it disappeard. Ill add it again.

Comment: FWIW, the version of NewtonSoft used in linqpad above was 5.0.6.16206

Comment: And I just said it - it works in all validators, when checking the JSON. The model isnt relevant, as I am not serializing to a model, just an object. There is no underlying object/class structure in this case.

Comment: And therefore, I noted that it was "completely irrelevant", because it is. I later clarified that, but the answer is still valid, as the "model" (class to deserialize too) isnt relevant in this case.

Comment: So... can anyone reproduce this bug? I tried and it runs fine on my machine.

Comment: I created a new console app, added Json.NET 6.0.8, pasted your code snippet and printed it out. It works perfectly. I cannot reproduce this error. http://i.imgur.com/Hb7Rk2T.png

Comment: Also just tested Json.NET 6.0.8.18111 in my linqpad example - also works here still.

Comment: And I tried 6.0.4.17603, and it still fails here...

Comment: Same here. Works fine. You should try to add more details about your program, i.e. the JS code used to send the JSON to the server, custom model binders (if any), code executed before the conversion. Maybe the full http request that sends the data. The problem is somewhere, just not in the portion of code you showed us.

Comment: Matteo: Thanks, but there is nothing of that. No sending, no http, no custom model binders, no network traffic at all. It is just hardcoded JSON text inside VS, and then the JsonConvert. Nohting else.

Comment: @Ted What .NET are you targeting? Try a new project? Reinstall .NET?

Comment: I have now downloaded a new DLL from the official webpage, and in a testproject, the same code as above works. So, something weird is going on with the DLL I was using, it seems.